# My Helpers.vbhtml file results in "Type 'ASP.global_asax' is not defined"

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I created the ASP.NET special folder called `App_Code` in my MVC project. I added a new file `Helpers.vbhtml` that will contain repeatedly-used razor code snippets.

[image: Folder structure]

**Helpers.vbhtml**

```
@Helper GetTime()
    @DateTime.Now
End Helper
```

But this results in the error `Type 'ASP.global_asax' is not defined.` (x2)

[image: Error]

Nothing seems to be affected - the application still compiles and runs. What's this error mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is caused by a naming conflict; there is a namespace called `System.Web.Helpers`.

The problem appears to be VB.NET-specific. I can't reproduce the problem in C#.

Rename the .vbhtml file to `Snippets.vbhtml` or something else that won't cause a naming conflict.

Comment: That's a weird error... it happen even if the helper files is named something like MyTemplateHelper.... but renaming it Snippets solved the issue :-)

Comment: This worked for me until I shut down Visual Studio and opened it back up again. Now I get the error again.

Comment: I have mine named CodeSnippetHelper.vbhtml and really any name you give it - it still give that error. Just FIY Mine Located in the App_Code Folder

Comment: Yeah it's a weird bug. I recall seeing the error coming and going, depending on what I named the file. It's strange but harmless, I guess. Not sure if newer versions of Visual Studio or ASP.NET MVC fix it. Maybe I'll try that.